# How to represent small changes in data in a graph

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, morris.js

I want to know how I can represent the small data changes in this graph. The changes are in second decimal place. I tried weighted average, a log of values, I couldn't succeed.

[image: Example]

Comment: Instead of showing the whole range [0, 4] on the y-axis, you could just show the interval [3.5, 4]. This will magnify the changes by a factor of 8.

Comment: The chart will render y-axis by itself. It's a morris chart.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ymin` and `ymax` properties of Morris to display a little better the small changes. You can set these properties with the min and max values of your data.

Please try the following snippet:

```js
var data = [
  { y: '2016-01', a: 3.5 },
  { y: '2016-02', a: 3.8 },
  { y: '2016-03', a: 3.7 }
];
  
var min = Math.min.apply(null, data.map(function (d) { return d.a; }));
var max = Math.max.apply(null, data.map(function (d) { return d.a; }));

Morris.Line({
  element: 'chart',
  data: data,
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
  labels: ['Label A'],
  resize: true,
  xLabelAngle: 40,
  parseTime: false,
  ymin: Math.floor(min), // min - 0.1
  ymax: Math.ceil(max) // max + 0.1
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way of showing small but statistically significant differences is to show deviation from mean in standard deviations. You've probably got means for each time slot, so the deviation of the sample mean from the global mean is scaled by root Nsample.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Let's say you've got 100 values for 2014, 144 values for 2015, 81 values for 2015. Calculate mean and standard deviation for all 325 values. Now we've got three points which represent the yearly means. Represent as standard deviations and scale by 10, 12 and 9 to plot.